# How to see the screen actually performing things while using XCTest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xctest

I am using XCTestCases and I want to see things actually happen on screen while tests are executed. But as i run the test cases , application gets started and closes in a second while it displays test suceedeed.

Comment: Suing for how much? :-)

Comment: And what exactly do you want to see? Normally there is absolutely nothing to see during tests.

Comment: I want for example I have written in test case that label.test = @"xyz"; , then I want to see this text on screen also.